# How to avoid "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" when working with nested Ruby hashes?

Tags: ruby, json, api, hash

I'm working with the Steam Storefront API - http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=240

I've parsed the JSON into a hash.

When I try to select any hash value nested inside of "data" I receive an "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error.

I can `puts` the whole lot with `res["240"]["data"]` which shows me all of the keys and values. All of which seem to look fine.

However when I try to go one branch further it throws nil.

```
res["240"]["data"]["type"]
```

Using `.key` also throws up an error.

```
res["240"]["data"].key
```

My quest to find an answer has mainly found suggestions of searching for the key & values, however I know the direct route to the data so I'd like to go this route if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on ruby 2.3, you may use `dig`, as suggested by @sawa.

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig

However, if you are not on ruby 2.3, then things get a bit trickier.

The simplest approach is to implement your own version of dig:

```
class Hash
  def dig(*path)
    path.inject(self) do |h, k|
      h.respond_to?(:keys) ? h[k] : nil
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can just `res.dig("240", "data", "type")`

Comment: @sawa answer works, however thank you for taking into consideration I might not have had 2.3 yet. It's rather lucky they released "dig" just before I needed it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dig` in combination with the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), like:

```
res&.dig("240", "data", "type")
```

If `res` is `nil` (or more accurately isn't "`dig`able") then it will return `nil` instead of raising.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dig`.

```
res.dig("240", "data", "type")
```

Comment: nil does not implement `.dig`: `[3] pry(main)> nil.dig("240", "data", "type")`
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'dig' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @tomsabin So what? How is that relevant to the question?

Comment: My misunderstanding of the question - thinking that `res` was originally nil.

Comment: Quote from the question: "I've parsed the JSON into a **hash**."